# Reactjs output is not showing

Tags: reactjs

I'm a newbie to reactjs and trying to test a very basic component, however it seems all my struggle is wasting of time because its not showing up in the browser.

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import '../HealthBlock.css';

class HealthBlock extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="block">
                        <div>
                            <h6>Total Healthy Employees</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div className="sec2">
                                <div className="num">55</div>
                                <div className="icon"><img src="./img/healthy logo1.svg"/></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="block">
                        <div>
                            <h6>Total ill Employees</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div className="sec2">
                                <div className="num">4</div>
                                <div className="icon"><img src="./img/healthy logo2.svg"/></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="block">
                        <div>
                            <h6>Total Employees</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div className="sec2">
                                <div className="num">65</div>
                                <div className="icon"><img src="./img/team (1).svg" style="width: 42.27px; height: 35.86px;"/></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="block">
                        <div>
                            <h6>Responses Submitted</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div className="sec2">
                                <div className="num">59</div>
                                <div className="icon"><img src="./img/healthy logo4.svg"/></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="block">
                        <div>
                            <h6>Responses Pending</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div className="sec2">
                                <div className="num">6</div>
                                <div className="icon"><img src="./img/healthy logo5.svg"/></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default HealthBlock;
```

Comment: Show all your code

Comment: Do you get any error in the console? Did you forget to use `ReactDOM.render(....)` method?

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving an "Invariant Violation" error, you need to remove or replace the style attribute you have against the `img` - it can't be a string:

```
<div className="icon"><img src="./img/team (1).svg" style="width: 42.27px; height: 35.86px;"/></div>
```

Best to organise your styles in your `HealthBlock.css` file anyway.

Edit: You can change the string version of the styles into an object if you want to keep the CSS there:

```
<div className="icon"><img src="./img/team (1).svg" style={{width: "42.27px", height: "35.86px"}}/></div>
```

Comment: Yes but you can't have styles like that on the `img`. I'll edit my answer with a potential solution.